# Including Linux Headers returns No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, header, kernel, header-files

I'm trying to write a C code that will make use of the memory information in Linux kernel (Virtual address space of a process, status of a process and such info.)

I'll need to include the below headers to get these info.

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/mm.h>
```

The actual files exists under the linux folder, but when compiling the file using gcc it returns that

> No such file or directory

Can someone please explain why i'm getting this error! and what should i do?

- I've already compiled the Kernel and installed all updates available (kernel version 3.16.0)

Comment: Have you installed the `linux-headers-3.16.0` if not install it using `apt get`? Another option is find those header files path and include the relative path when you compile in `gcc` using `-I` flag.

Comment: *The actual files exists under the linux folder*  The compiler is looking in `/usr/include/linux`, but cannot find it there. Maybe it is in some other location? Try to add `-I [path to (parent of) linux folder]` so the compiler knows where to look!

Comment: I installed the headers, compiled using `gcc -I` , now i'm getting this error `fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory
 #include <uapi/linux/stddef.h>` while i'm not including such a header in my code

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question.

Install the missing package `kernel-devel` using `apt-get`

NOTE: I've mentioned `apt` install package you can use what is supported on your system for example `yum`.

If you're not able to install kernel-devel then you can try this which install generic Linux headers.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then you can check where the init.h or module.h using `locate` utility

and then add the path in your compilation using `-I` flag.

```
gcc -g your_file.c -I/usr/path/of/the/kernel/header/include
```

Comment: There is no indication that the OP is using a Debian-based distribution.  They might, but this is hardly a general distro-independent "the answer to your question".

Comment: OK, I will add use the install package software yum or sudo apt or what package is available.

Comment: I installed the headers, compiled using `gcc -I` , now i'm getting this error `fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory #include <uapi/linux/stddef.h>` while i'm not including such a header in my code

Comment: Why are you giving entire path of header? Instead give #include <stddef.h>, this up to the installation of glib you can ignore that header and #include <stdio.h> that will also link.

Comment: I'm not sure where this come from! the headers i'm including in my code are calling other header files! and this is how files look after I've installed the headers! all include has this /linux path in them!!!